# Thermal decomposition of calcium carbonate

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

Thermal decomposition of calcium carbonate.

In general, we heat $\ce{CaCO3}$ to temperature of approximately 825°C it decomposes into calcium oxide and liberates carbon dioxide gas:*

$$\ce{CaCO3} \overset{825\ ^\circ \text{C}}{\ce{ ->}}\ce{CaO + CO2}$$

Is it possible to heat the calcium carbonate at temperatures below 825 degrees Celsius.

Comment: Do you mean "Is it possible to achieve the same effect heating the calcium carbonate at temperatures below 825 degrees Celsius?"

Comment: Yes, complete calcite at temperatures below 825 degrees Celsius.

Answer (score 2):

Pump a hard vacuum and calcium carbonate will calcine at a lower temperature.  825°C is about one atmosphere of carbon dioxide at equilibrium.  Thermodynamics proposes, kinetics disposes - finely ground goes faster than bulk.

Comment: In the US we activate molecular sieves in a vacuum oven around 150-200 C.  In Canada, they use porcelain bowl and a Meeker burner underneath.  If nanostructure is important, go cooler.